# Зачем нужны пространства имён в PHP

Tags: php, namespace

Здравствуйте!

Меня интересует, в чем преимущество использования **namespace** в **php**?

Сейчас у меня все классы подключаются через автолоад и классы размещены в соответствии с PSR-0, тоесть класс ***ClassParent_Class_ClassChild*** находится в ***/classes/ClassParent/Class/ClassChild.php***

Если использовать namespace, то для меня изменится только то, как я буду вызывать класс:
как сейчас - **ClassParent_Class_ClassChild**, или с namespace **\ClassParent\Class\ClassChild** (об алиасах я знаю, но не считаю это преимуществом)

Не исключено, что я чего-то не понимаю. Поэтому и задал вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

Очень хорошая [статья](http://habrahabr.ru/post/132736/) на этот счет!

И конкретно по вашему вопросу, отвечаю комментарием из [статьи](http://habrahabr.ru/post/72033/#comment_2064054): используя пространство имен, мы гарантируем существование наших библиотек (моего кода и стороннего) в абсолютно разных пространствах, что означает — вообще никто никого затирать не будет.

Comment: Спасибо, но я читал эту статью.

Я знаю, что пространство имен дает дополнительную вложеность, но в моем примере эта же вложеность обеспечивается использованием файловой структуры приложения. 

И я специально написал, что все классы подключаются автоматически (_autoLoad()). Чтобы это работало и с namespace? мне нужно так же раскладывать файлы классов по папкам исходя из пространств имен. 
Тоесть \Core\ClassName будет находится в /Core/ClassName.php.

Comment: "Затирание" не исключено как с вариантом через нижнее подчеркивание, так и с использованием namespace, так как для этого достаточно будет выше в файловой системе положить класс с таким же именем в такую же папку (каскадная файловая структура).

Comment: @DimkOf ну вопрос прозвучал, общественность ответила!